# I lost my friend's queen

Tags: cats, lost-pet

My friend gave me a queen for breeding with my tom. They were having fun last night and now the queen has disappeared. I looked around my house and then I also look into neighbor houses but I can't find the queen. Is there any way the queen will come back as my tom does, though the queen has stayed in my house for only two days?

Comment: put some feed out for her

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your friend know immediately what happened, so that they can be involved in the search, perhaps by walking around the neighbourhood and calling for the queen. They will also know the queen's favourite food or treats, and you can use that to help lure the queen back.

Comment: i tried everything to find her but i lost her :D

Answer (score 3):

A cat that is new to your home [should not be let outside within the first 3-4 weeks](http://www.hallplaceveterinarycentre.co.uk/clinical-information/moving-house.html). So if you have a cat over at your place for just a few days, it is best to not let it get outside at all, since it doesn't know that this is the place she is supposed to be (and it doesn't even have a strong bond with you!).

Now we are already past that point. It frequently happens that cats [run to their old home after people moved to a new house](http://www.hallplaceveterinarycentre.co.uk/clinical-information/moving-house.html). Therefore maybe Queen is running home to your friend's house.

Some suggestions of what you can do now:

- As mhwombat suggested: get your friend involved as soon as possible.
- Make sure someone stays at your place.
- Make sure someone stays at your friends place to be available in case Queen returns home.
- Check the paths between your two houses.
- If she doesn't return soon, put up search posters in the area around your house and between your house and your friend's house.

Good luck finding her!

Answer (score 0):

If you think she is outside, put her crate outside. If she came with a towel of anything in the crate, put that out too. Leave food and water as well. If you're lucky, you will find kitty curled up in the crate in the morning.